# Beautifulsoup4, BS4, Python Parsing Question

Tags: python, html

I am parsing a webpage using bs4.  There are more then one data type I would like to select, with the same class name.

My parsing code:

```
rows_ranking = soup_ranking.select('#current-poll tbody tr .left')
```

The page I want to parse has two different ".left" identifiers in the table rows.  How can I choose which one I would like.  Here is an exmample of two of these table rows (one I would like my program to parse, the other I would like to ignore)

1 - `<td class="left " data-stat="school_name" csk="Baylor.015"><a href="/cbb/schools/baylor/2020.html">Baylor</a></td>`

2 - `<td class="left " data-stat="conf_abbr" csk="Big 12 Conference.015.001"><a href="/cbb/conferences/big-12/2020.html" title="Big 12 Conference">Big 12</a></td>`

As you can see they have the same class identifier.  Is there a way I can have bs4 look only for the first of the two?

I hope my question makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: The links do not correspond to anything.

Comment: It was supposed to be raw code but didn't have backticks on it.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? They clearly have other attributes to distinguish them, right? Have you read the BeautifulSoup docs?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used BS4 or python for awhile, but If I remember correctly something like this should work on getting all elements with data_stat and school_name in the data.

```
results = soup.findAll("td", {"data_stat" : "school_name"})
```

Or if you want all results in data with the data_stat attribute and the value doesn't matter use -

```
results = soup.findAll("td", {"data_stat" : True})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can use soup.find_all and loop through your results.
2. Use the css selector for first.
3. Inspect and copy the selector for that element.

Comment: Right, except there are 50 items returned with my call function.  I want to grab every OTHER item.  I suppose some python looping where I can grab every other item would work fine enough.  But I am more curious to see if there is another way to have bs4 grab based solely off the 'data-stat' html thingy.  I am not strong in html, i don't think that is a selector.

Comment: You mean the data-stat attribute, and a selector can be any unique identification of an element. Either answer here though will get you what you're looking for.